# jQuery Validation - How to use for steps in a wizard like form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I want to use [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) with [jQuery UI Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs). How I can validate using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) on each step triggered by next button. I see examples of [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and mostly are for validation of whole form at once. I need it step by step.

I am not a pro so please tell me some easy solution instead of suggesting me other plugins. My code looks like:

```
$("#frag1").click(function(){
     //I need jQuery Validation code here for a single step
     event.preventDefault();
}else {
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
         $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
         return false;
   });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your use only one form. So, call http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element  and put that validation code for current frag, add this code in next button click event. Check with all other methods. For know you can go with this solution. I am new to validation plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that you didn't want suggestions for other plugins. But I think this could be especially useful for you:

There is the jQuery formwizard plugin, http://thecodemine.org/

Which integrates nicely with the jquery validation plugin. And also is themeable with jQuery-UI themes (if you are already using them on your site).

Comment: How to make tabs for each steps using that plugin? Like I am using on my site please see link above.

Comment: Better option to move this plugin.. it seems more functions comes with default. no need to write your code.

Comment: Hi @Imran you're right I don't think you'll be able to easily use a tab like wizard for formwizard, however like Naga says formwizard comes with a lot of functionality, so you may wish to use formwizard as it may have other features that might come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

On next step button click check for which fragment div did not have "ui-tabs-hide" this css class. Then try to apply same CSS class (e.g:- "myinputs") for all inputs and checkbox and soon. Then apply validation for current "fragment" div inputs validation.

For example:-
if I am in step 2. Then this div "fragment-2" won't have css class "ui-tabs-hide". You can see that class applied to other dives.

So, try to get current active div ID (here it is "*fragment-2*"). Then do like this

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

```
 $("#myform").validate().element( "#myselect" ); // here there are passing element ID

$("#myform").validate().element('#'+ CurrentFragment + '.myinputs'); //here we are passing current fragment css class inputs.
```

I am not sure it will accept css class. But try once else loop and handle false element and  `return false` with out any step. So, user won't move to next fragment until he set values.

I not sure this is best idea. I don't have much knowledge about that validation plugin.